# Can I use "how long" without a continuous tense?

Tags: perfect-constructions, continuous

> How long **have I slept**?

Can I say that just before waking up? I think so.
The problem is that "how long" implies a continuous tense in most cases. In this case you can't use with a continuous tense since you are not asleep anymore. So I don't know if it really works.

I know I can use other ways of asking this question:
"How long have I been asleep?"
"How long was I sleeping?"

Comment: _Before_ waking up? That's clever! Of course you can use _how long_ without the continuous - you can ask "How long did Mozart live?" "How long did it take you to get here" etc. etc.

Comment: It sounds as if you have been taught a common but wrong understanding of continuous constructions in English.  The choice of continuous or not continuous is about how the speaker is choosing to present the events, not necessarily about **any** objective quality of them. You can use a simple past about any event, no matter how long it took, if it serves your purpose to talk about it as a completed event: _after life evolved on Earth_, for example. Conversely you may choose to view a brief event as continuing as long as it had _some_ extent in time: _While the bottle was falling of the table_

Answer (score 1):

There are several meanings of the present perfect.  One meaning, when combined with a "since {time}" or "for {time period}" is to describe a state that continues until the present.  So it is correct to say

> I've slept for 8 hours / I've slept since 10pm.

There may be more idiomatic ways to express those ideas, but grammatically these are correct.

And so it is also correct to ask  "How long have I slept?".

However it may be more idiomatic to emphasise the continuous and temporary nature of this state (since most people don't sleep for more than a few hours) and say "How long have I been sleeping"